# copying a file on remote server using cat command not working

Tags: bash, shell, expect

I am trying to copy a file  on remote server  using below  expect script.
I cannot use   scp or  sftp  etc.

```
#/usr/bin/expect

set timeout -1

spawn /usr/bin/ssh -q root@testserver cat /tmp/passfile > /tmp/localpassfile

expect "assword"

send "welcome1\r"

expect eof
```

Its  not  working.

But below command   works fine when i execute on shell

`ssh -q root@testserver cat /tmp/passfile > /tmp/localpassfile`

Comment: Please [format your code properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting), and explain what _Its not working_  exactly means.

Comment: Don't have a system I can test this on at the moment but I suspect the redirect is being applied to the spawn, not the ssh output. Try escaping it (`spawn '/usr/sbin/ssh -q root@testserver cat /tmp/passfile >/tmp/localfile'`

Comment: Hi Wayne       I tried your  suggestion.   but its not  working        I am getting bwlo error      [testuser@testserver ~]$ expect  exp1.exp
spawn ssh -q root@targetserver cat /etc/passwd > /tmp/passfile
couldn't execute "ssh -q root@targetserver cat /etc/passwd > /tmp/passfile": no such file or directory
    while executing
"spawn "ssh -q root@aeldb1cel01 cat /etc/passwd > /tmp/passfile""
    (file "exp1.exp" line 4)

Comment: Expect does not understand shell's I/O redirection. You can write like this: `spawn bash -c "/usr/bin/ssh -q root@testserver cat /tmp/passfile > /tmp/localpassfile"`

Comment: Thanks a lot.  this  works  and servers my purpose

Comment: adding   bash -c   to command  worked perfectly and i am able to download the file

Answer (score 0):

You are now passing the output to `/tmp/localpassfile` on `testserver`. Try:

```
/usr/sbin/ssh -q root@testserver "cat /tmp/passfile" > /tmp/localpassfile
```

Comment: it says  cat /tmp/passfile   No such file or directory

Comment: In that case `/tmp/passfile` does not exist on the target server. Make sure it exists.

Comment: In addition to above:

`laurens@ws41:~$ /usr/bin/ssh -q root@laurenstest "cat /tmp/passfile" > /tmp/localpassfile`
`laurens@ws41:~$ cat /tmp/localpassfile `
`example1`
`laurens@ws41:~$ /usr/bin/ssh -q root@laurenstest "cat /tmp/passfile"`
`example1`